# Tomcat:How can I configure server.xml dynamically?

Tags: java, linux, web-applications, tomcat, jndi

I want to use Tomcat's connection pooling (using embedded database H2) but I would like to resolve the `url` at runtime, i.e. put the path of the database 
in a relative manner.
The problem is that I can not hard code a path for tomcat (even using a relative path like `..\webapps` or something)
since

1. I don't know where it will be installed
2. Tomcat's startup script will start from an init.d script so
   something like `..\webapps` will not work.
3. Also I found out I can not put environment variables in
   `server.xml`.

What is the standard/best way to approach this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you're using a database like Hypersonic or SQLLite where you need a file path.

You should put the database in the CLASSPATH (e.g. WEB-INF/classes of your WAR).  Access it using a classpath resource reader rather than an absolute file path.  It'll make your app more portable and these shenanigans with Tomcat unnecessary.

Comment: +1: You are right, I am using `H2`.But how does this help?I mean I need a `url` for the `JNDI` resource definition in `server.xml` right?So how will this work if I just put it in classpath?

Comment: I have no say in this.It must be file based.So isn't there a way to dynamically configure the path in server.xml?

Comment: I see it added to the context.xml in the link, but it's an absolute Unix path: http://groups.google.com/group/h2-database/msg/c56a8470f08289f2?pli=1

Comment: I was hoping that this is a frequent issue and there is a standard solution.I can't depend on absolute paths and Tomcat doesn't accept environment vars in `server.xml`.So I am stuck

Comment: Try another database besides H2.  If you have a common database that you could connect to this problem would go away.

Comment: But the problem is the `JNDI` set up.In the other database I would also need connection pooling.So I still be in the same problem

Comment: No, you wouldn't.  You set up the JNDI connection pool in the context.xml; you don't need to edit server.xml.  And having a real shared database running as a server obviates the need for having to install anything.  This problem has been solved many times over, every day.  You aren't the first.

Comment: But in all the example I have seen the `server.xml` is always modified.And in case of `context.xml` I would still need a url to the database.
Also I am supposed to use an embedded database.

Comment: (sigh)  Context.xml makes it possible without editing server.xml.  Yes, you need a URL.  Yes, you need a database that's separate from your web app that runs in server mode.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom Resource in your context.xml, with an object factory defined by you. Have that factory create the connection and return it.

Comment: How can I implement my custom `Object Factory`?Do you have a reference to give me for me to study?

Comment: @Jim Have a look at the Tomcat server.xml/Resource documentation. There is a piece there about custom resources. The Object factory is an instance of `javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory`.